# How to Prevent URL redirection on Form Submission if the process.php is on a different domain

Tags: php, forms, webforms, submit, form-submit

Greetings everyone!

I need help with this code. For example, I have two websites: **firstwebsite.com** and **secondwebsite.com**

My form is on **firstwebsite.com** and the data are processed on the process.php of **secondwebsite.com**

What is happening is when someone submits the form in **firstwebsite.com** , the web page is redirected to a webpage in **secondwebsite.com**

What **I want to happen** is

1. to stop the form submission from redirecting to the web page of **secondwebsite.com**
2. instead of redirecting, a dialog box should appear telling the user that form have been submitted, thus the current form still remains on the page of **firstwebsite.com**

I've been looking for answers and I've tried several codes but none work.

Please paste the entire code or script or ajax that I should use.

```
<html>

 <head>
    <title>document</title>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv">
      <form name="sampleform" action="secondwebsite.com/process.php" method="POST">
      <p><input type="text" name="phone"/></p>
      <div id="phone-status"></div>
      <p><input type="text" name="fname"></p>
      <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
      <p><input type="submit" name="SubmitForm" value="SEND"></p>
   </div>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

Comment: such code formatting is annoying, dude. Try to write concise and clean.

Comment: Is it possible that when the target iframe is loaded after clicking SEND, that is the time the alert will be called? I tried the onload but the alert is being called already without the target iframe being loaded

Answer (score 2):

just use HTTP redirect. You have to use it anyway.
Simply add

```
header("Location: http://firstserver.com/thanks.html");
exit;
```

in the form handler.
that's all

Answer (score 1):

`target` the form at an iframe, call the alert from the `onload` event of the iframe.

Comment: Hi, David, thanks for answering. Hope you can help me how to exactly do that. Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. I used target="postFrame" and <iframe name="postFrame"></iframe> ...The page is no longer directing but the web page of secondwebsite.com is in the iframe. Is there a way that instead of showing the secondwebsite.com page on the iframe, it should show a custom made page that says "Submitted"?

Comment: No. Hence the suggestion to use JS in the onload event. You can hide the iframe if you don't want it visible.

Comment: Is it possible that when the target iframe is loaded after clicking SEND, that is the time the alert will be called? I tried the onload but the alert is being called already without the target iframe being loaded

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more complex method, but should render xhtml code.

When the user clicks the submit, you take the data using ajax, the pas it on using curl to the target page.

You can the dynamically change the form field to the success message upon success.

Will need a bit of work, but should do fine.